# VisualStudio crash on startup - Error:"streamjsonrps.remoteinvocationException: could not load file or Assembly System.Linq"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly

I'm getting error message when start Visual Studio 2017 Community version.
At crash with below error message:

```
Could not start visual studio due to an error.StreamJsonRpc.RemotelnvocationException
Could not load file or assembly System.Linq, Version=4.O,O.O,
Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= bO3f5f7f1 1 d5Oa3a or one
of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an
assembly manifest.
```

[image]

I re-install visual studio, but still getting same error message.
Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: The error message about System.Linq is quite serious, it indicates disk corruption.  Lots more can go wrong beyond that.  Replace the disk drive.

Comment: @HansPassant - I not get a single message regarding disk failure or hardware failure related error. I don't think need to replace disk drive for this error.

Comment: Anyone have proper solution?

Comment: Can you try reinstalling .NET and also StreamJsonRpc?

Comment: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1602 check this out.

Comment: could you please `re-install` VS as administrator

Comment: @Saif - I reinstalled visual studio but it not work.

Comment: @OjasviBhargava - That post seems related to error on build solution, I'm getting this error on visual studio startup time.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue workaround. try this command in the  in run window "devenv /ResetSettings"

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the following

1- Stope any antivirus
2- Open Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017
2- run "devenv /nosplash"

I hope this can fix the issue